# Combing panel data with cross -section counter-factual?

Tags: panel-data, treatment-effect

I have a panel dataset of a treatment group with no control group panel.  It has been proposed to me that I use cross-section from a a national survey, taken at baseline and same time as post-treatment, as a counter-factual (survey is the same questions).

Then I would use propensity score matching to match control households with treatment.

I have never done something like this, and it feels wrong to me when I first think about it (heterogeneity in cross-sections), but is this possible?

Thanks you!